# Create a symlink for the libmysqlclient.18.dylib library

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql through a pkg installer. 
I am trying to start rails server and I am getting the following error.

```
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
```

I am reading that a solution to that is to create a symlink like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

There is no

```
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

file only a

`/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib` file.

I run

```
sudo find /usr/ -name libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

and I can't find the libmysqlclient.18.dylib file.

Comment: The symlink fix does not apply to your situation the *18* file was for a previous version (5.6 I believe).  The *20* file is used with mysql 5.7.  If you are upgrading from a previous version, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html and run `mysql_upgrade`.

Answer (score 16):

I encountered a problem like this while setting up a new development environment. I had installed MySQL via homebrew, which gave me version 5.7.9 of MySQL, with the library version `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`.

In my case, I was setting up a python project. The requirements install failed because the python-MySQL connection piece was looking for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`, which was nowhere to be found on my machine.

Downgrading to MySQL 5.6 solved the issue for me:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew install mysql56
```

Now `/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` is present and everything's peachy.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with homebrew, but I think you meant `brew install mysql56`, not `brew cask install mysql56`.

Comment: Thanks, made the change

Comment: Thanks. I've spent a day trying to get this to work, and finally you gave me a solution that worked :D

Comment: I installed mysql using these steps but still didn't have a `/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. I did have a `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. Hopefully symlink will do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

The `mysql2` gem which is most likely in your Rails environment is still looking for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` (from what must have been a previous mysql install) but the library is no longer there because the recent manual install/upgrade replaced it with `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`.

The easy fix is to install again `mysql2`:

`gem uninstall mysql2 && gem install mysql2`

or better yet:

`gem uninstall mysql2 && bundle`, if you are on Bundler.

Answer (score 3):

I did not have mysql installed through brew or gem, and was facing the same issue that it was looking for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` instead of `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`. I tried everything mentioned here and at some other threads. Nothing worked. Finally, this worked for me:

```
 pip install mysqlclient
```

It does not install `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`, but solves the `library not installed` and `image not found` errors.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall mysqlclient
2. Clear cache of your pip
3. Find folder in which pip wheel cache is stored for mysqlclient and delete it.
4. Reinstall mysqlclient

mac mojave OS cache will be in this folder:  ~/Library/Caches/pip. Follow the steps below:

1. Find  ~/Library/Caches/pips/wheels/ | grep mysql
2. Delete the file you got.
3. pip install mysqlclient